# Get Python 3 from bash file using similar syntax for Python 3

Tags: python, bash, python-3.x

I am writing an install script and is trying to get a variable linking to Python 3 instead of Python 2. In bash you can do:

```
:~$ export PYTHON="${PYTHON:-python}"
:~$ echo $PYTHON
/usr/bin/python2
```

How would you call similar syntax for Python 3 instead? I have tried

```
:~$ export PYTHON="${PYTHON:-python3}"
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: have you installed python3? give it the full path

Comment: Depends on your specific operating system's python3 packaging. In some places it's `python3`, but on others you need something like `python34` or `python35`. Without knowing a specific distro or operating system, there is no answer we can provide that will certainly be correct.

Comment: Also, `export PYTHON="${PYTHON:-python}"` is actually in your scenario **exactly the same** as just `export PYTHON`: It's reusing the value already set in the environment, not changing it at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your original, Python 2 code doesn't do what you think it's doing:

```
:~$ export PYTHON="${PYTHON:-python}"
:~$ echo $PYTHON
/usr/bin/python2
```

This is because `${foo:-bar}` expands the variable named `foo`, or -- if that variable is either unset or set to an empty value -- expands instead to the value `bar` as a default. If the result is not `bar`, then that means that `$foo` must already be set to a non-`bar` value.

The logic of this command is roughly thus:

- If no shell variable named `PYTHON` exists, or such a variable exists but with an empty value, then export an environment variable -- and also set a shell variable -- named `PYTHON`, with a value being `python`. (Not `/usr/bin/python2`, but exactly `python`, those six precise characters).
- If a shell variable named `PYTHON` does exist with a nonempty value, then export it with its current value to the environment. (If that variable is already exported, then this line has no effect).

Since `echo $PYTHON` is emitting as output `/usr/bin/python2`, then this means that `PYTHON=/usr/bin/python2` must have been true **before** your original command was invoked at all.

---

If, unlike your original command, you want to disregard the original value of the `PYTHON` shell variable (or environment variable, if it's already been `export`ed), then you should do something like the following:

```
PYTHON=$(type -P python3) || {
  echo "python3 not found" >&2
  exit 1
}
export PYTHON
```

The `export` is done as a separate command here so that the exit status of `export` does not override the exit status of `type`, which would prevent errors from being detected.